# AVPlayer - how to reset play button

Tags: ios, stream, mp3, avplayer

Im working on a app which stream a audio file online.  The code below is working, but when the audio file ends, the play button don't reset. The button is still pressed, and before the user can play the audio file again, the user have to press the button 2 times.

My question is: How do i reset the play button automatically after the audio file ends?

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)togglePlayPauseTapped:(id)sender
    {
        if(self.togglePlayPause.selected) {
            [self.audioPlayer pause];
            [self.togglePlayPause setSelected:NO];
        } else {
            [self.audioPlayer play];
            [self.togglePlayPause setSelected:YES];

            self.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
            NSString *urlString = @"MYURL";
            NSURL* urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            AVPlayerItem * currentItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:urlStream];

            [self.audioPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:currentItem];
            [self.audioPlayer play];




        }

    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate of audioPlayer to self and make sure the designated ViewController can receive AVAudioPlayer Delegate calls. Then implement the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method and call your `togglePlayPauseTapped` method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self togglePlayPauseTapped:nil];
}
```

The total should look something like this:

[image: total picture]

Edit:

And change this

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
```

To this:

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
```

Comment: I tried the above example, but i get a issue with self.audioplayer.delegate=self;

Comment: Are you sure you added **<AVAudioPLayerDelegate>** to the interface?